# Which video player is embedable in a swf and supports VAST or VPAID

Tags: flash, video-player, vast

We have a flash application, and we want to show our videos on the website. But we would also like to show advertisements in this video. For the advertisements we need a player that is compatible width VAST or VPAID, and that is embeddable in flash. We already investigated JWPlayer 6, but that one seems very hard to embed (it would require altering the source code of JWPlayer). Is there a video player that allows for embedding into flash, and for serving ads with VAST/VPAID?

For us it is not an option to change the whole flash application into a HTML 5 application.

Answer (score 0):

Try https://github.com/flowplayer/flash

There is VAST & VPAID support, but I've not used it.